# Replace variable in CSV using Powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, csv, scripting

I have a messy CSV file that gets generated each week. This is what I start with:

```
Company,Division,Department,Location,Job Title,Username
1-Acme INC,9000-CSD,6003-CSD IT,2-Downtown,IT Technician,user1
1-Acme INC,9000-CSD,6002-CSD HR,2-Downtown,HR Generalist,user2
```

What I really want is this:

```
Company,Division,Department,Location,Job Title,Username
Acme INC,CSD,CSD IT,Downtown,IT Technician,user1
Acme INC,CSD,CSD HR,Downtown,HR Generalist,user2
```

Basically I just want to strip the "[numeric]-" portion of that field. I have searched high and low and found different variations of replacing a CSV string with powershell, but haven't found the right syntax to replace variable text in a CSV using powershell.

This is what I have so far. When I check the output, nothing has changed.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test.csv
$csv | %{ $_ -replace "^[0-9]+-"}
$csv| Export-Csv .\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not process the csv file as a text file?  You can still import the resulting output file as a csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$csv = get-content .\test.csv
$csv = $csv -replace "[0-9]+-", ""
$csv | out-file .\test.csv
```

or line 2 could be just:

```
$csv = $csv -replace "[0-9]+-"
```

Comment: When I tried that, it actually killed all of my text in the CSV file and replaced it with this:

Length
388

Comment: Need line feeds to do this right, but hopefully you can figure it out.
`$csv = "1-Acme INC, 9000-CSD, 6003-CSD IT"
 $csv = $csv -replace "[0-9]+-"
 $csv `

returns 

    Acme INC, CSD, CSD IT

for me.

Comment: Note that I've removed the ^ as that caused it to only replace the numbers at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Tony, this is what I was trying to get away from. We have thousands of possible options here, so I may as well not script it if I have to enter each possibility. I was hoping to use regex to just replace the "numeric-" entries.

Comment: The import-csv I think is the sticking point here.  I was using the $csv variable as if you were using get-content.  Let me test it...

Comment: Yeah--use get-content instead of import-csv.  And then to save it use "$csv | out-file .\test.csv"

Comment: You may need to use [string]$csv = get-content... so that it uses a string type instead of arraay object.